# How to read the an object from text file and assign to a a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the below object structure present in text file how do I have read this and assign to a list.

```
 "ID": 1,
  "PatientNumber": "12",
  "Honorific": "Mrs.",
  "FirstName": "Abc",
  "DisplayName": "Abc",
  "Gender": "Female",
  "DateOfBirth": 41881,
  "Age": 0

  "ID": 2,
  "PatientNumber": "123",
  "Honorific": "Mrs.",
  "FirstName": "xyz",
  "LastName": "xyz",
  "DisplayName": "xyz",
  "Gender": "Female",
  "DateOfBirth": 41881,
  "Age": 0
```

I tried using split "," but was not able to get value of each property

Comment: That looks like JSON without the surrounding `{` and `}` to make it an object. Are you sure your file doesn't have a JSON object in it?

Comment: Having said this: what did you try so far? We're not here to just give you the code so you can copy-paste it. Just try something and post here, when you're stuck at a specific point.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged C#, ASP.NET and .NET, I assume you want to set this data to a Class and append it to a List.

If you're sure that data is not a JSON array then you can use the following code:

```
var data = File.ReadAllText("PATH_TO_FILE");

var stringDataArr = data.Split("\r\n\r\n");

List<DataObject> dataObjects = new List<DataObject>();

foreach (var stringData in stringDataArr)
{
    var dataObject = new DataObject();

    foreach (var propValues in stringData.Split(",\r\n"))
    {
        var prop = propValues.Split(":")[0].Trim('"').Trim();
        var value = propValues.Split(":")[1].Trim().Trim('"');
        
        foreach (var objectProp in dataObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (objectProp.Name == prop)
            {
                if(objectProp.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                {
                    objectProp.SetValue(dataObject, int.Parse(value));
                }
                else
                {
                    objectProp.SetValue(dataObject, value);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    
    dataObjects.Add(dataObject);
}


public class DataObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PatientNumber { get; set; }
    public string Honorific { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

This is not a best practice. It's written for your data. It probably won't work with different data.